# Как проверить на undefined?

Tags: javascript

Есть код который выводит сумму чисел в массиве, без наибольшего и наименьшего значения. Не могу проверит входное значение на undefined.

Пробовал проверять таким способом:

```
if (typeof something === "undefined") {
    alert("something is undefined");
}
```

Но тесты не прохожу, мне нужно если undefined то выводить просто 0.

```js
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}

function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
}

function sumArray(numbers){
  var maxPlusMin = getMaxOfArray(numbers) + getMinOfArray(numbers);
  if (numbers && isNaN(numbers) & (numbers.length  != 0) ) {
  return numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){  
    return n + sum;
  }, -maxPlusMin );
  } else {
   numbers = 0;
  }
}

alert(sumArray([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 10 ]));
```

Comment: Ну а `return numbers;` поставить? Или сразу `return 0;`? И например сменить `&` на `&&`?

Answer (score 2):

@Visman в комментарии указал на мой недочёт:

> Ну а return numbers; поставить? Или сразу return 0;? И например сменить & на &&?

Так всё работает как нужно:

```js
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}

function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
}

function sumArray(numbers){
  var maxPlusMin = getMaxOfArray(numbers) + getMinOfArray(numbers);
  if (numbers && isNaN(numbers) && (numbers.length  != 0)) {
  return numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){  
    return n + sum;
  }, -maxPlusMin );
  } else {
   return numbers = 0;
  }
}

alert (sumArray([ 6, 2, 1, 8, 10 ]));
alert (sumArray([]));
```